# assign class based on condition results in razor

Tags: html, razor

I currently have this code

```
@if(true) { <text> <td class="add"></td> </text> } else { <text> <td class="remove"></td> </text> }
```

I would like to switch to something like this

```
<td> @if(true) { <text> @class="add" </text> } else { <text> @class="remove" </text> }</td>
```

I am not sure if this is correct, or the right syntax for it

Answer (score 0):

```
@functions {
    object getAttributes(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
        {
            return new {@class="add"};
        }
        return new { @class="remove"};
    }
}

<td>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName,@getAttributes(style))   
@getAttributes(style)
<td>
```